# Git push to shared hosting ftp

Tags: git, ftp

I have a shared hosting program that doesn't support git. So I was wondering if it is possible to first push your commits to an sort of layover server (a raspberry pi) which will then automatically upload that to ftp. I found an service called git-ftp but I think that is not what I mean. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setup a git repo on the pi.

Add it as a remote in your project.

`git remote add pi path/to/pi/repo.git`

Create a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to do your deployment (FTP/rsync/etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I perform such an git hook to pass it through?